# Is the comma misplaced in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following excerpt has been taken from *Birth* by A.J. Cronin. I think there is a mistake in the second sentence -- or, if it is correct, I do not understand its grammatical pattern. Is the comma after *waiting that* correct? I think that either there should not be a comma, or it should go before 'that.'

> Andrew smiled faintly. He saw that the old woman, wise in experience,    realised there must be a period of **waiting that,** she was afraid he would leave the case, saying he would return later.

Answer (score 2):

You must have a badly scanned copy, for at Google Books one finds:

> Compass - Volume 1
>
> Andrew smiled faintly. He saw that the old woman, wise in experience,
>   realized there must be a period of **waiting, that** she was afraid he
>   would leave the case, saying he would return later.